# Lasso Regression - Finding multiple candidate models

Tags: regression, linear-model, lasso

I have 20 predictors and I am attempting to find several candidate models to then test.

I am using the LassoCV library, my following code provides me with the alpha and co-efficients of a model.

```
model = LassoCV(cv=3,max_iter=1000).fit(predictors,      returns.values.ravel())
```

My question is: how do I get multiple candidate models, since this only provides me with 1 set of alpha and co-efficients.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the lasso_path function? It provides a coefficient path, but no cross-validation error. Documentation can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.lasso_path.html#sklearn.linear_model.lasso_path)

Comment: Why do you want multiple candidate models? Typically, the point of LASSO is to choose a particular set of predictors for a model.